# React, Material-UI onKeyboardFocus value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, material-design, material-ui

how to make exact same thing as onKeyboardFocus but in my own component? I want to make my own versions od these material's-UI

I don't really understand what it is and I don't know hot to accomplish that effect. Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=onKeyboardFocus

Read their codebase and documentation to understand. Else you'll never be able to write your own material-ui library.